# Multiple Developers on One Site (PHP)

Tags: php, version-control

Not a direct relation to PHP but at the moment we have 3 developers working on one site. We are using shared hosting so cant get svn or cvs installed.

**Answered**

Is there any way we can implement version control on shared hosting?

**Unanswered**

On a side note, I have seen a lot of developers have a comment at the top of their files, i.e. this one from Invision Power Board I have from using it a few years ago

> /**
>    * Invision Power Services
>    * IP.Board v3.0.5
>    * Wrapper for interfacing with stopforumspam.com
>    * Class written by Matt Mecham
>    * Last Updated: $Date: 2009-02-04 20:05:25 +0000 (Wed, 04 Feb 2009) $
>    *
>    * @author      $Author: bfarber $
>    * @copyright   (c) 2001 - 2009 Invision Power Services, Inc
>    * @license     http://www.invisionpower.com/community/board/license.html
>    * @package     Invision Power Services Kernel
>    * @link        http://www.invisionpower.com
>    * @since       Tuesday 22nd February 2005 (16:55)
>    * @version     $Revision: 222 $
>    */

Is there anyway to automatically generate these into files, also updating the "Last Updated:" section?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary at all that the hosting has the possibility to run the revision control system. But you definitely have to introduce it into your development environment!

We develop all our projects using SVN over unfuddle. This means we have central repositories for all our projects, where we commit to/update from. There are many cheap or free repo spaces like [GitHub](https://github.com/), [unfuddle](http://www.unfuddle.com) or [Google Code](http://code.google.com).

All you need is such a space, an IDE that supports revision control (with every IDE has to) and a suitable deployment strategy, meaning a good way of uploading the right files to the server at the right moment, etc. Usually you tag stable versions of your app and upload these repo tags.

Comment: Just had a look at unfuddle, seems to be something that I'm looking for. Will check it out in more detail

Comment: I would also check out beanstalk.  Their web hooks system can help create some helpful release management processes.  www.beanstalkapp.com

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution would be using Git/Mercurial/SVN/etc. (not CVS, it's ancient and horrible) during development and write a deployment script which uploads either the newest release tag or simply the most recent snapshot to your shared hosting server.
That script would obviously be located somewhere in your local network where all devs can access it - you might want to add some checks if another deployment is already running so dev 2 can't start it if dev 1 has already started it and it's not finished yet.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on an example script which handles the user permissions? I'm trying to use rsync to upload a group of files from the developers git repositories, but i have problems with the user/group permission.

Answer (score 1):

try beanstalk svn  http://beanstalkapp.com/